# Postgres: Permission denied for all but phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion, osx-server

Just installed OS X Server for Lion. I'd heard that the default database is now Postres - which is good news. Bad news - I can't connect to it.

I've tried using psql, createdb and Navicat, and all return the same thing: "Could not connect to server: Permission denied." This is using the _postgres role and using my own role which I've added as a superuser to postgres.

The weird thing is, **phpPgAdmin** has no trouble at all in connecting. Neither do I when I'm running as root and use `psql -U`. But if I just straight up `pqsl postgres` or `createdb whatever` then it flat-out refuses to work.

Here's a summary:

```
gormster$ psql postgres           # permission denied
gormster$ createdb whatever       # permission denied
gormster$ sudo psql postgres      # role "root" does not exist
gormster$ sudo su -
root# psql postgres               # role "root" does not exist
root# psql -Ugormster postgres    # THIS WORKS
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it magically started working again. Not sure what it is I did to get it to happen, but it may have been adding myself to the _postgres group. If you're unaware, there are instructions for adding yourself to a group [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071101100044328).